# What does the phrase 'move the will' mean?

Tags: meaning, phrase-meaning

What does 'move the will' mean
E.g. Francis Bacin says "The duty of rhetoric is to apply reason to imagination for the better moving of the will.”

According to the dictionary 'will' means resolve, desire or determination so would 'moving the will' mean to influence?

Thanks in advance

Comment: This is not my homework. Please stop making assumptions. I've been searching all over the web and I just can't find a definite answer. One site says that it means that rhetoric inspires people to act more virtuously?

Comment: The edit makes this a ton better. Especially the inclusion of your own research and a reference to a dictionary. Thanks very much for that. Yes, you understand the sentence correctly; the dictionary def you found is the right one. PS: unless we’re talking about two different people, it’s Francis  Bac**o**n.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The will is that part of the soul/psyche/mind/brain, whatever you prefer, that motivates us to act. I can know as an intellectual matter that I should exercise more, but my will must be engaged for me to get off the couch and move. Bacon is saying that a good coach would use the power of rhetoric to fire up my imagination to inspire me to do what my reason knew was right.